# Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database:

Tags: magento2

While migrating from linode to aws, getting this below error, version is: 2.3.4.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Mageice_AdminPaymentMethod schema: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
Mageice_AdminPaymentMethod data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Mageice_AdminPaymentMethod schema: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
Mageice_AdminPaymentMethod data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#2 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#3 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#4 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#5 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

So as described in exception, I have run the  bin/magento setup:upgrade command, and got the below error:

Notice: Undefined index: oauth_consumer in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152

What could be the issue. Please help.

Comment: did you do as follow?  Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade"

Comment: ya did that, got this error with that command: Notice: Undefined index: oauth_consumer in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152